# UIAlertController not being shown

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uialertview

this is my `ViewController.swift`:

```
import Intents

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func getdbb() {
            db().getdb { (Db) in
                let alert1 = UIAlertController (title: "Random Trivia", message : Db,  preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: nil,  message: "Do you want to go to the next question?", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .default, handler:{ action in self.getdbb() }))
                    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title :"NO", style: .default, handler: nil ))

                }))
                self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                INInteraction(intent: GetQuestionIntent(), response: nil).donate(completion: nil)

        }

    }

}
```

and I have a query button in my main.storyboard which is connected to the `getdbb` function, yet the alert UI is not shown in the simulator. This is what happens when I click the query button (output is only shown in Xcode):

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the closure where you present the UIAlert has been executed in the main thread?

Comment: Add breakpoint where you present the alert to confirm (a) you’re on the main thread; and (b) you hit that line at all.

Comment: The code of `db().getdb()` would be great. Check the you really call inside it the closure.

Answer (score -1):

You are not presenting the controller in the Main Thread, so try as below:

```
db().getdb { (Db) in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert1 = UIAlertController (title: "Random Trivia", message : Db,  preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: nil,  message: "Do you want to go to the next question?", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .default, handler:{ action in self.getdbb() }))
                    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title :"NO", style: .default, handler: nil ))

                }))
                self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
                INInteraction(intent: GetQuestionIntent(), response: nil).donate(completion: nil)

        } 
}
```